# Grouping by anonymous types in LINQ with non keyed values

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm trying to group a LINQ query to find duplicate values. According to MSDN if i specify the properties as non-keyed it should ignore them when evaluating the expression:

From MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx

```
Dim prod7 = New With {Key .Name = "paperclips", Key .Price = 1.29,
                  .OnHand = 24}
Dim prod8 = New With {Key .Name = "paperclips", Key .Price = 1.29,
                  .OnHand = 423}
' The following line displays True, because prod7 and prod8 are
' instances of the same anonymous type, and the values of their
' key properties are equal. The equality check does not compare the
' values of the non-key field.
```

My code:

```
 Dim query = people.GroupBy(Function(i) New With
 {Key i.EmailAddress, Key i.LastName, Key i.FirstName, i.ID}).
 Where(Function(g) g.Count() > 1).ToList()
```

I expect the code to return some results, it returns zero. If i remove i.ID i get the expected number of results.

Comment: @DStanley It's not the GroupBy that is doing the filtering, it's the Where that is filtering and it finds no records because the GroupBy never has more than 1 in the group.  The simple answer is that the GroupBy should not have ID as part of it's key.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is LINQ's GroupBy function does not use the keyed properties.  That said, this is what I believe you are looking for:

```
Dim query = people.GroupBy(Function(i) New With
 {i.EmailAddress, i.LastName, i.FirstName}, Function(i) New With { i.ID}).
 Where(Function(g) g.Count() > 1).ToList()
```

This version of GroupBy already has the Keyed properties and non-keyed properties separated out into separate lambda functions.

In fact, I'd go so far as to say, forget the Key properties entirely.  I've never actually seen them used, and the implementation described in the MSDN article would be very counter intuitive.  Two entities with only **some** properties being equal being considered equal is very odd behavior.